# Select2 showing error for ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

[image]I want to use select2 with data using ajax request. But its showing this error

```
Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.
```

**HTML**

```
<select id='myselect' class='select2-input select2'>
    <option></option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var base_url = $('#baseurl').val();
$("#myselect").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a State",
        allowClear: true,
ajax: {
    url: base_url + 'selecttest',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    quietMillis: 50,
    data: function (term) {
        return {
            term: term.term
        };
    },
    results: function (data) {
        return {
            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    text: item.expense_detail,
                    id: item.user_id
                }
            })
        };
    }
}
});
```

**Getting JSON Response Like this**

```
[{"expense_id":"2","user_id":"5","expense_detail":"abcdh1","amount":"123","expense_date":"2016-10-18","expense_type":"pocket","team_code":"0","team_id":"0"},{"expense_id":"3","user_id":"5","expense_detail":"hxyz1","amount":"123","expense_date":"2016-10-11","expense_type":"","team_code":"45664654","team_id":"46546"},{"expense_id":"4","user_id":"5","expense_detail":"abch2","amount":"123","expense_date":"2016-10-11","expense_type":"","team_code":"45664654","team_id":"46546"},{"expense_id":"5","user_id":"5","expense_detail":"abh3","amount":"123","expense_date":"2016-10-11","expense_type":"","team_code":"45664654","team_id":"46546"},{"expense_id":"6","user_id":"5","expense_detail":"ah4","amount":"123","expense_date":"2016-10-11","expense_type":"","team_code":"45664654","team_id":"46546"},{"expense_id":"7","user_id":"5","expense_detail":"h5","amount":"123","expense_date":"2016-10-11","expense_type":"","team_code":"45664654","team_id":"46546"}]
```

**I'm using this select2 version**

Copyright 2012 Igor Vaynberg

Version: 3.2 Timestamp: Mon Sep 10 10:38:04 PDT 2012

Any Help is much appreciated..Thank You.

Comment: Since you are using `Select2` which is below version 4, you need to place a hidden element like `<input type="hidden" id="hiddenElem" style="width:300px" />` and should your existing initialization as `$("#hiddenElem").select2({...........`  Otherwise adapt to version 4 of Select2

Comment: @ArturFilipiak The Question Is Why that error is showing ............Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.

Comment: @DavidR Thanks I'm checking it.. once it worked I will comment here.

Comment: WHY DOWNVOTED...... !

Comment: @DavidR I'm facing an issue, I'm using 4.0.3 now..now with every request why 'term' query string contains this  ../selecttest?term%5B_type%5D=

Comment: You mean in the `network` panel of your `devtools` right? not in the web url if I'm not wrong?

Comment: Between, I didn't downvote :)

Comment: @DavidR Yes.. when I try to get the values in php, like $_GET['term'] at server side, it return the $_GET['term'] value as {"term":"g","_type":""} .  Also for select2.js it is showing error TypeError: b is undefined .....:(

Comment: I presume you're using the same old code without my hidden field suggestion since you're using version 4 and above.. Am I right?

Comment: Yes my code is old but I have replaced select2 css and js file by version 4.0.3 now..so I'm not using hidden field..

Comment: Updated my question..added json response..please check

Answer (score 1):

`Select2` expects the result to come with `ID` and `TEXT` attributes, Hence you you need to rewrite your results callback as,

```
            results: function (data) {
                var tmpResults = [];

                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    tmpResults.push({
                        'id': item.user_id,
                        'text': item.expense_detail,
                    });
                });
                return {
                    results: tmpResults
                };
             }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You have something like `return {term: term.term};` as an input to the `data` attribute, I guess you have an extra `term` there, it needs to be `return {term: term};`

Comment: I put term: term.term, because term object contains some other properties also, like _type, so I wanted to pass only the string that we input into the search box. So term.term contains that string..it is returning json data also..I think the problem is only appending the json reponse into that select box..........

Comment: Okay, Here is an example which I have put it in a fiddle mimicking your json  (which is hosted in myjson.com to be consumed as a rest call). It seems to be working as expected. Please check it here - http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/747/

Comment: Thanks @David R..Its working using input field. But why its not working using select element....as I showed in my html  <select id='myselect' class='select2-input select2'>....!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Basically, Select2 library manipulates the given html input control as a div and populates/renders the select2.

Comment: Can you please accept/upvote my answer in that case?